# Npm/Bower Install

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, zsh, bower-install

I was just wondering if anyone could help me with setting up Bower properly. I do believe there is something wrong with the path to the packages in my project and therefore can't install any packages with the 'bower install ' command. It keeps returning this error:

[The Bower error that keeps getting returned when the command is run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn3T2.png)

If you notice the first line with 'argv ... ' I'm not sure if the path is correct or whether I would need to change the path in this instance at all. I have Npm v2.15.1 installed and also Node v4.4.3 installed which is the dependencies needed to install Bower but it is still not working. I installed Node via their website so I don't think that could be causing any issues.

If anyone think's they could point me in the right direction as I have looked for a solution on the internet but nothing I seem to try works.

Appreciate it!

Comment: The output says you don't have sufficient permissions to delete a file and adds "Please try running this command again as root". Have you tried that? Looks like you already have `bower` installed but it can't be removed so the new install fails. Are you user `pd21`? Was the original installation done by this user? Check the permissions set for the files in `/Users/pd21/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/bower`.

Comment: Hi Hugo thank you for your response, it's weird because I'm PD21 I've installed Bower but can't seem to run the command too install the packages for my front-end dependencies. But as you mentioned it's because of th permissions I did try running the command 'sudo' which I know isn't great but it still fails. The original installation was done by myself which is why I', so bemused by it. How would I go about checking the permissions for that file path? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Try `ls -la /Users/pd21/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/bower/CHANGELOG.md` and add the output to that in your question. You can also try to remove `/Users/pd21/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/bower` manually using your file explorer or `rm -rf /Users/pd21/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/bower`